# Is it worth updating Plesk to newer versions?

Tags: vps, update

I have a VPS running Plesk (on a 32bit Centos 5, i think).

Plesk is currently at version 9.5.2.

The Updates section show there are new versions available:

*Plesk Panel 10.0.0 Upgrading to the new control panel version*

*Plesk Panel 10.0.1 Upgrading to the new control panel version*

*Plesk Panel 9.5.3  Updating or adding new components*

*Plesk Panel 9.5.4  Updating or adding new components*

Is it worth running those updates? I randomly come across posts by plesk users saying they've had issue with upgrade so I'm sure if it's really worth my time.

If it is, does it make sense to incremently run the update or install the newest directly? 
ie. go from 9.5.2 to 9.5.3 first, then 9.5.3 to 9.5.2, and so forth,
or go to 10.0.1 directly.

**EDIT:** I'm aware that plesk 10.0 looks and act pretty differently to 9, i've got it on another VPS so i'm not worried about that

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure that your license covers Plesk 10.0 too! If that's the case I don't see anything harmful about upgrading, I've done that myself between Plesk 9.x versions (I don't have a 10.x license boo)

Comment: @lynxman. How does one check if the license covers 10.0 as well?

Comment: It's tricky... if you didn't buy the license it's almost for sure that it'll only cover 9.x only, I personally didn't risk it

Comment: I paid extra money for plesk through the hosting company. I'll check with them. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate this an old question, however it's worth pointing out that since this question was posted there have been several remote vulnerabilities in Plesk which have been patched in 9.5.4.

If you are running a version of Plesk before 9.5.4 you should upgrade to 9.5.4 as soon as possible. Running the upgrade process will also install microupdates which will have fixes for these exploits.

lynxman's answer still stands, however - if you're planning an upgrade to Plesk 10 (or 11) ensure your license key supports this.

Comment: Thanks for the late contributions. I did go through the update process at the end but stuck to the 9.x.x branch. I'm sure other people coming here will appreciate this security warning.